# Understanding the xdebug trace log

Tags: php, xdebug

Okay!

I know some people are gonna freak out at me, but, I tried searching, couldn't find anything and so I am asking this.

> 0.4917    2292504    +1288     -> MongoCollection->findOne()
>   /var/www/public_html/s.php:157

This is a line from my trace log. What do the first three numbers mean?

I have `xdebug.show_mem_delta=On` in my php.ini

`MongoCollection->findOne()` is name of the function,

`/var/www/public_html/s.php:157` is file:line.

What does `0.4917`,`2292504`,`+1288` mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
0.4917   Execution time
2292504  Memory usage
1288     Change in memory since last output
```

From http://www.xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace example with mem_delta turned on,

```
0.0003     114112  +114112   -> {main}() ../trace.php:0
0.0004     114272     +160     -> str_split('Xdebug') ../trace.php:8
0.0007     117424    +3152     -> ret_ord($c = 'X') ../trace.php:10

//114112 = 114112 - 0
//160 = 114272 - 114112
//3152 = 117424 - 114272
```